# Moq rethrow error passed into Setup

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

so I've got an error handling class that uses the interface:

```
public interface IEventLogger
  {
    void WriteError(Exception ex, string message);
  }
```

So I'm mocking this up with [Moq](https://code.google.com/p/moq/) for unit testing. This method would normally just log the error into the event viewer but for my unit test I want it to rethrow the exception passed into the method, i.e. I want the unit test to fail if an error is passed into this mocked class. Any ideas how I can do this?

I got this far:

```
 var moqIEventLogger = new Mock<IEventLogger>();
 moqIEventLogger.Setup(s => s.WriteError(It.IsAny<Exception>(), 
                                           It.IsAny<string>()));
```

But I wasn't sure how to access the original exception, if it's possible at all??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it to only fail then use `Throws` method like:

```
moqIEventLogger
            .Setup(s => s.WriteError(It.IsAny<Exception>(),It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Throws<InvalidOperationException>();
```

If you want it to throw given as argument exception try:

```
moqIEventLogger
            .Setup(s => s.WriteError(It.IsAny<Exception>(),It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Callback((Exception ex, string s) => { throw ex; });
```

Comment: Bottom one was what I was looking for. Just tested, works like a charm

Answer (score -1):

Add this in ur setup (modified)

```
    moqIEventLogger.Setup(s => s.WriteError(It.IsAny<Exception>(), 
                                       It.IsAny<string>()))
                  .Callback<Exception ex, string s>(p =>
                  {
                         throw ex;
                  });
```

Assuming u hv class ClassA with method MyMethod where u ur calling WriteError method Your Assert should look like:

```
 Assert.Throws<Exception>(ClassA.MyMethod );
```

Comment: Thaty just throws a new exception. I want to **rethrow** the original.

Comment: modified answer...sorry for not reading the complete question. And thanks for downgrading it :-)

Comment: That's even worse. That won't compile. @Rafal has the answer.